# How can i make each key in a dictionary a string and make the value of that key a Python list

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary, key

I am trying to convert a dictionary key to a string and make the values a list

this is where i am and i don't know what to do next

```
dict_from_csv = pd.read_csv('Emissions.csv', header=None, index_col=0, squeeze=True).to_dict()

keys = list(dict_from_csv.keys())
values = list(dict_from_csv.values())
keys
values
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a few example rows (in text format) from `Emissions.csv` and also what the output should be for it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a unique string to represent all the keys? If yes, you can do this:

```
keys = " ".join(list(dict_from_csv.keys()))
```

And, Do you like a single list with all values? If yes, you can do this:

```
values = [val for key in df for val in dict_from_csv[key].values()]
```